# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to get the current longitude and latitude using Cordova/PhoneGap. But I'm getting this error on **fail** function:

> Position retrieval timed out.

I have set the maximumAge to 5000 and timeout to 10000.

This is the Cordova code snippet I'm using:

```
getCurrentPosition:function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {

    argscheck.checkArgs('fFO', 'geolocation.getCurrentPosition', arguments);
    options = parseParameters(options);

    var timeoutTimer = {timer:null};

    var win = function(p) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutTimer.timer);
        if (!(timeoutTimer.timer)) {

            return;
        }
        var pos = new Position(
            {
                latitude:p.latitude,
                longitude:p.longitude,
                altitude:p.altitude,
                accuracy:p.accuracy,
                heading:p.heading,
                velocity:p.velocity,
                altitudeAccuracy:p.altitudeAccuracy
            },
            (p.timestamp === undefined ? new Date() : ((p.timestamp instanceof Date) ? p.timestamp : new Date(p.timestamp)))
        );
        geolocation.lastPosition = pos;
        successCallback(pos);
    };
    var fail = function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutTimer.timer);
        timeoutTimer.timer = null;
        var err = new PositionError(e.code, e.message);
        if (errorCallback) {
            errorCallback(err);
        }
    };

    if (geolocation.lastPosition && options.maximumAge && (((new Date()).getTime() - geolocation.lastPosition.timestamp.getTime()) <= options.maximumAge)) {
        successCallback(geolocation.lastPosition);
      } else if (options.timeout === 0) {
        fail({
            code:PositionError.TIMEOUT,
            message:"timeout value in PositionOptions set to 0 and no cached Position object available, or cached Position object's age exceeds provided PositionOptions' maximumAge parameter."
        });

    } else {
        if (options.timeout !== Infinity) {
            timeoutTimer.timer = createTimeout(fail, options.timeout);
        } else {
            timeoutTimer.timer = true;
        }
        exec(win, fail, "Geolocation", "getLocation", [options.enableHighAccuracy, options.maximumAge]);
    }
    return timeoutTimer;
},
```

Everything seems to be ok. But it doesn't call **successCallback** function. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've solved this, and I don't see which options you are sending to the `getCurrentPosition` method, but i made it work on wp8.1 with these options:

```
{
    timeout: 20000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 90000
}
```